# Facebook login in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a doubt, with reagrds to integrating facebook authentication, in my rails app. And, would really appreciate, someone's help, and advice.

I have done the initial requirement. I have got the app_id, and secret id. And, I have attached my omniauth.rb, file, below. If someone can have a look and let me know, what I am doing wrong, that would be highly appreciated. And, the gem, has been bundled.

The error, I am getting is, "The parameter app_id is required".

OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_590736697630795'], ENV['FACEBOOK_52c90a73196b3f5f4a3761b588211155']

Comment: Please add the failing code if you want to get some help.

Answer (score 0):

Use Devise, it supports omniauth facebook , follow this tutorial : 
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Comment: where did you put the App_id that facebook gave you? Show me the code

Comment: Devise.setup do |config|
  #
  config.mailer_sender = 'please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com'

 
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'
config.omniauth :facebook, "676039522494694", "aa84491d325260bc3b614cc108ebca03"

  # config.authentication_keys = [ :email ]
config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]
    config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :username ]

  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :username]

  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]

Comment: i put App_id in\ to devise.rb